# PHP - PATH_INFO issues

Tags: apache-2.2, php, configuration

This might belong on the stackoverflow.com website, but I don't think so, because this has to do with Apache configuration.

I'm getting the an error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: PATH_INFO
```

This is a stock Apache configuration, and I thought that you could just use the `AcceptPathInfo On` in httpd.conf:

```
<Directory "/srv/http">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    AcceptPathInfo On
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

What exactly do I have configured wrong here?

Comment: Can you specify how you are trying to get the value in PHP?

Comment: Exactly - are you using $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] to retrieve the data? What's shown if you make a PHP file with <?php print_r($_SERVER); ?> in it?

Comment: Ya, I was using `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to a configuration issue on my end that was overlooked.

Comment: Probably faced a similar problem here, the directive AcceptPathInfo which must be set to On on the <Directory> you wish to use the PATH_INFO variable.